# remove statusbar from CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, statusbar

I am using this code to create a simple CKEditor without a status bar but it's not being removed... why?

```
<textarea cols="80" id="txtArticleComment" name="txtArticleComment" rows="20" required></textarea>
<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor"> with an CKEditor
    // instance, using default configurations.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtArticleComment', {
        language: 'ar',
        uiColor: '#14B8C4',
        resize_enabled: 'false',
        removePlugins: 'elementspath',
        toolbar: [
            [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
            [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ],
            [ 'BidiRtl', 'BidiLtr' ],
            [ 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyBlock' ],
            [ 'Blockquote', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar' ],
            [ 'Preview', 'Maximize' ]
        ],
        height: 100,
        width: '100%'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have the `resize` plugin enabled? Try disabling it.

Comment: which resize plugin? how to disable it?

Comment: fixed it by using false as bool instead string like this resize_enabled: false thank you